# How to select QT version within NetBeans

Tags: c++, qt, netbeans

I am using:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- NetBeans 8.1
- QT4, QT5

I want to build a QT application with `#include <QtWidgets>` inside NetBeans. I found that NetBeans cannot compile it because NetBeans is using QT4.

I do `qmake -v`, and get:

```
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.2.1 in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

My question is how to make NetBeans uses QT5 libraries?

Comment: You should add your Qt bin path to your PATH environment variable and launch again NetBeans.

Comment: Thanks for you reply, I did `echo $PATH` and get `/home/sflee/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games`. I did `whereis qmake` and get `/usr/bin/qmake /usr/bin/X11/qmake`, is that mean I have already included the bin path of qt5?

Comment: I'm not sure. In which path did you install Qt?

Comment: Sorry for asking this simple question, I was just learning to set up development environment on linux. I install qt by `sudo apt-get install qt4-default`, `sudo apt-get install qt5-default`. Then I used `whereis qmake`, and I found it is located at `/usr/bin` which I found it also inside `$PATH` so I guess I have already included the bin path of qt ~"~

Comment: No problem at all! :) Yes, that's right. So in this case, NetBeans should detect the Qt 5 version.